# How to extract certain strings start with a symbol from a text file in python?

Tags: python, string, extract, symbols

How can i extract all words start from symbol '$' from a text file?

File a (ascii) -->

```
        @ExtendedAttr = nvp_add(@ExtendedAttr, "severity", $severity,  
 "description", $description, "eventID", $eventID,
             "eventURL", $eventURL, "alertLevel", $alertLevel, 
      "eventStart", $eventStart,
             "eventSourceCount", $eventSourceCount, "eventSourceTable", 
$eventSourceTable, "eventDestCount", $eventDestCount)
```

I want the output to be like this (all in new line) :

```
$severity
$description
$eventID
$eventURL
$alertLevel
$eventStart
$eventSourceCount
$eventSourceTable
$eventDestCount
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `regex`:

```
>>> import re
>>> with open('filename') as f:
...     ans = []
...     for line in f:
...         matches = re.findall(r'(?<!\w)(\$\w+)', line)
...         ans.extend(matches)
...         
>>> print ans
['$severity', '$description', '$eventID', '$eventURL', '$alertLevel', '$eventStart', '$eventSourceCount', '$eventSourceTable', '$eventDestCount']
```

Now use `str.join` to get the expected output:

```
>>> print "\n".join(ans)
$severity
$description
$eventID
$eventURL
$alertLevel
$eventStart
$eventSourceCount
$eventSourceTable
$eventDestCount
```

Comment: If i have text like below:

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions, noticing the escaping of `$` (usually line-end) with `\`. Read the entire file at once with `f.read()` (Which can also be extracted to another line for enhanced readability)

```
import re

with open("filename", "r") as f:
...     matches = re.findall("(\$\w+)", f.read())
print matches
```

Comment: This would also match `'foo$bar'` and reading the entire file at once is usually not a good idea.